# How to get latest executed TC without duplicate

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server for my project and displaying some metrics in my page.
One of my metrics have TC executed count but its showing TC Executed with duplicated entry also.

How can get the TC recently Executed list without duplicate??

My SQL Server query is:

```
SELECT 
    a.tc_id tc_id,
    a.status STATUS,
    MAX(a.exn_time) exn_Time,
    'auto' tctype
FROM 
    auto_details a WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE 
    a.status IN ('Pass', 'Fail')
    AND project = 'proj2'
GROUP BY 
    a.tc_id, a.status
```

In the below output display both fail and pass list for same tc_id. but I want distinct executed list (exn_Time have last updated list) only.

[image]

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected output. I don't understand the question.

Comment: I don't see any duplicated entries... One is Passed while other is Failed

Comment: but i want latest record only

Comment: question is not clear plz provide sample an expected output sample

Answer (score 0):

```
Create Table Auto_Details (tc_id varchar(8000), Status varchar(8000), exn_Time datetime, project varchar(8000))
Insert Auto_Details Values ('TC_001', 'PASS', '2016-05-16 15:47:27.580', 'proj2')
Insert Auto_Details Values ('TC_001', 'FAIL', '2016-05-16 15:52:14.787', 'proj2')
Insert Auto_Details Values ('TC_002', 'FAIL', '2016-05-16 15:47:27.580', 'proj2')
Insert Auto_Details Values ('TC_002', 'PASS', '2016-05-16 12:43:27.580', 'proj2')

With cteMetrics As
(
Select tc_id, exn_time, Status,
        Row_Number() Over (Partition By tc_id Order By exn_Time Desc) Sort
    From Auto_Details with(NOLOCK)
    Where status IN ('Pass', 'Fail')
        AND project = 'proj2'
)
Select *
    From cteMetrics
    Where Sort = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that what you want is something more like this:

```
;WITH cte
(
    SELECT  *, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tc_id ORDER BY exn_time DESC) AS exn_no
    FROM    auto_details
    WHERE   a.status IN ('Pass', 'Fail')
      AND   project = 'proj2'
)
SELECT a.tc_id      tc_id,
       a.status     STATUS,
       a.exn_time   exn_Time,
       'auto'       tctype
  FROM cte a 
 WHERE exn_no = 1
```

Also, FYI, `nolock` is inherently unreliable and can result in inconsistent transient values, especially on grouping/partitioning queries.